# How to show some text in html when certain condition is met in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show some text in html only when certain condition inside an input box is met. Otherwise, hide it. I am using AngularJS. Below is my html code.

```
  <form novalidate="" class="simple-form">conditional_number 
  <input type="text" ng-model="conditional_number " ng-change="search_number()"/>
```

If the conditional_number in the input box exceeds 5, I want the text `Text to appear if condition is met` to be displayed.

In AngularJS, there are `ng-switch, ng-hide / ng-show, ng-if` and perhaps more. I am at a loss which is the most appropriate. How can this be appropriately done in AngularJS?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, i've added a working example

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan: Thanks. The working example was very helpful!

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan: 2 more minutes before I can mark it as answer. Will do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply achieve it using    `ng-show`

Take a look at this

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YPdV2/7/)**

```
 <form novalidate="" class="simple-form">
  <input name="myfield" ng-model="conditional_number" ng-minlength="5" ng-change="search_number()>
    <span ng-show="conditional_number.length>5">Good boy!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: @RobH  user3293156 has mentioned that he want text to be print when input text box length size exceeds 5. Its working fine

Comment: Oh I see. I thought "If the conditional_number in the input box exceeds 5" meant literally the number 5, not a 5 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ng-show` is the most appropriate here:

```
<form novalidate="" class="simple-form">
  conditional_number 
  <input type="text" ng-model="conditional_number" ng-change="search_number()"/>
  <span ng-show="conditional_number> 5">Text to appear if condition is met</span>
```

This clearly communicates your intention to only show when the conditional number is greater than 5.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/128PcOUdLPmfu2d1GIp5?p=preview) for you.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful too. I have upvoted but I can only choose one answer.